# Drupal : How to create a String with condition 'if included?

Tags: php, string, if-statement

Is is possible to create a String variable like this :

```
$myString = 'the weather is ' . if ($weather == 'good') {'very good'} else {'very bad'};
```

It means that if my variable $bad contains the value 'good', $myString is equal to :

```
'the weather is very good'
```

I know that I can divide my line in some others instructions but I want to do in only ONE instruction.

Do you understand what I want to do?

Thank you very much,

Bat

Comment: There's nothing Drupal-specific about this, so I removed the Drupal tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick for you.

```
$myString = 'the weather is ' . ($weather == 'good' ? 'very good' : 'very bad');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$myString = 'the weather is ';
$myString .= ($weather == 'good') ? 'very good' : 'very bad';
```